# using nested while loop instead of for loops

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-lists

I created a coding challenge for me

I want to change the values of a nested list
using a  while loop without creating a new list

this function works well with a single row nested list see example below

basically it works like:
start the loop checks if first value is a specific type if so repaces the value
go out of the loop, start the loop again--> the first value is already replaced so the index is updated
and it precedes with the next value till all values are replaced

```
def insertdata(data):
    data_added = False
    n = len(listoflist[0])
    index = 0

    while not data_added and index != n:
            if listoflist[0][index] is None:
                listoflist[0][index] = data
                data_added = True

            else:
                index += 1

            if index == n:
                print("\n The list is full, No more elements will be added \n")
```

I want to extend the function so it can replace nested lists with multyple rows and columns

the output should be somethinge like that

```
listoflist = [[None, None, None],[None, None, None]]

def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input

while True:
  def insertdata(_execute()):


input = 2

[[2, None, None],[None, None, None]]

input = 4

[[2, 4, None],[None, None, None]]
```

here im little bit stuck

my pseudocode:

```
rowindex = 0
main loop 
 # start second loop 
  start second loop 
  # performs the operation for the row [rowindex][columnindex]
  # if all values replaced in the row
  # go back to main loop update the row count and procede with the next column
```

aproach so far, not working as expected

```
def insertdata(data):

    row_index = 0
    while row_index != len(listoflist):

       # inner loop
        data_added = False
        n = len(listoflist[row_index])
        index = 0

        while not data_added and index != n:
            if listoflist[row_index][index] is None:
                listoflist[row_index][index] = data
                data_added = True

            else:
                index += 1

            # gets not executed
            if index == n:
                row_index += 1
                break
```

problem is how to update the rowindex in the outer loop, and start the inner loop with the updated rowindex ?

example for single row list

```
listoflist = [[None, None, None]]

def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input

while True:
    insertdata(_execute())
    print(listoflist)
```

Comment: what results are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
listoflist = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]

def insertdata(data):

    row_index = 0
    while row_index < len(listoflist):

       # inner loop
        data_added = False
        n = len(listoflist[row_index])
        index = 0

        while index < n:
            if listoflist[row_index][index] is None:
                listoflist[row_index][index] = data
                data_added = True
                break
            else:
                index += 1

        if index == n:
            row_index += 1

        if data_added:
          break


for i in range(7):
    insertdata(f'input {i}')
    print(listoflist)
```

This gives you this result

```
[['input 0', None, None], [None, None, None]]
[['input 0', 'input 1', None], [None, None, None]]
[['input 0', 'input 1', 'input 2'], [None, None, None]]
[['input 0', 'input 1', 'input 2'], ['input 3', None, None]]
[['input 0', 'input 1', 'input 2'], ['input 3', 'input 4', None]]
[['input 0', 'input 1', 'input 2'], ['input 3', 'input 4', 'input 5']]
[['input 0', 'input 1', 'input 2'], ['input 3', 'input 4', 'input 5']]
```

You were having issues with indexes and not breaking the while after a new element was added to the list

Comment: can you explain when and how  `if data_added:` gets executed ?, after the inner loops breaks ?

Comment: Yeah, every time a new input is added to the list you need to break both while loops because if you don't the input will be added to the entire list. So you see, anytime a new input is added, data_added is set to True and we break the first loop, we validate if the index of the nested list is equal to the length of the list, and finally, we break the outer loop. Sorry, English is not my native language so maybe I'm confusing you more,